# C++ Record on mouse release

Tags: c++, logging, mouseevent

I am trying to get a program to write to a text file when the left button on the mouse is released, and only released. Below is the code that I have tried. In the GUI there is a slider that the user can move back and forth to zoom in and out on a video with. I want to be able to grab just the value the user stops at. Currently it prints the starting and stopping values as well as all the values in between. I thought that getting it to print the stopping value on the mouse release would work. Currently it still just prints all the info not just on the mouse release.

```
if(WM_LBUTTONUP)
{
    myfile1.open("testing.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    myfile1 << "testing";
    myfile1 << "\n";
    myfile1.close();
}
```

Comment: The `if` statement is malformed. You have to make a comparison. What you have is just comparing against a literal, `WM_LBUTTONUP`. Perhaps you meant `uMsg == WM_LBUTTONUP`?

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is always true because `WM_LBUTTONUP` is a non-zero constant. You should compare a `uMsg == WM_LBUTTONUP` in your [WindowProc callback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633573%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).